# Inspecting a remote graphql endpoint with graphiql

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

There is a graphql endpoint which I don't own but which provides a public endpoint. I'm hoping to introspect it using graphiql. I'm totally new to graphql, so I don't even know if this sort of thing is possible.

I have the [graphiql example](https://github.com/graphql/graphiql/tree/master/example) running locally and am modifying [server.js](https://github.com/graphql/graphiql/blob/master/example/server.js) to try to make it work. Poking around at other SO threads has gotten me this far...

```
var introspectionQuery = require('graphql/utilities').introspectionQuery;
var request            = require('sync-request');

var url = 'http://endpoint.com/graphql';
var response = request('POST', url, { qs: { query: introspectionQuery } } );
var schema = JSON.parse(response.body.toString('utf-8'));

// herein lies the rub
schema = new GraphQLSchema(schema.data.__schema);

var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.use('/graphql', graphqlHTTP(() => ({
  schema: schema,
})));
app.listen(8080);
```

This code blows up in the GraphQLSchema constructor, trying to make a schema out of that introspection query. Clearly that's not quite the right approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to build schema out of the introspection result is `buildClientSchema`:

```js
var buildClientSchema  = require('graphql/utilities').buildClientSchema;
var introspectionQuery = require('graphql/utilities').introspectionQuery;
var request            = require('sync-request');

var response = request('POST', url, { qs: { query: introspectionQuery } });
// Assuming we're waiting for the above request to finish (await maybe)
var introspectionResult = JSON.parse(response.body.toString('utf-8'));
var schema = buildClientSchema(introspectionResult);
```

You could build the schema in two other ways: `buildASTSchema` and instantiating `GraphQLSchema` directly, which is what you're trying out. `GraphQLSchema` constructor takes in an object with `GraphQLSchemaConfig` type:

```
type GraphQLSchemaConfig = {
  query: GraphQLObjectType;
  mutation?: ?GraphQLObjectType;
  subscription?: ?GraphQLObjectType;
  types?: ?Array<GraphQLNamedType>;
  directives?: ?Array<GraphQLDirective>;
};
```

And those two utility modules provide easier ways to build the schema from either from introspection query result or parsed IDL type definitions, respectively by using `buildClientSchema` or `buildASTSchema`. Refer to those modules in [graphql-js/src/utilities](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/tree/master/src/utilities) directory for more information please.

Comment: That worked! I just had to do `buildClientSchema(introspectionResult.data)`.

Comment: So then the followup question would be how to use graphiql to post queries back to that endpoint...

Comment: For that you could look at the example index.html code we have in here: https://github.com/graphql/graphiql/blob/master/example/index.html#L95

Comment: Basically with your server implemented with `/graphql` endpoint, configure your graphiql by writing a `fetcher` function to pass your query from client side to server side.

Comment: maybe you would like to check this out https://gist.github.com/geocine/c93ba07c9956f403f0f11ff9c1b39a55

Answer (score 0):

I was trying this with a PHP GraphQL library. I hit lots of issues experimenting with the above around CORS (cross origin security stuff).

Then I discovered GraphIQL is available as a Chrome app. That resolved my need, so noting here in case useful to anyone else who comes across this issue. You don't need to do any coding to get GraphIQL working with a remote endpoint.